# Remove elements from array matching specific value in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following array

```
[0] => 1009
[1] => 1033
[2] => 2052
[3] => ANNEX 4E
[4] => Bill of Lading
[5] => CERTIFICATE OF ANALYSIS
[6] => CERTIFICATE OF ORIGIN
[7] => DHL - 5130431633
```

i want to remove the value with DHL followed by any number. any value containing DHL i want to remove.

for example DHL - 5130431633 or DHL - 51304345654 should be removed number in front of the dhl do not matter

i have use the following code but it do not work

```
$xmlarrayresultdocsave = preg_grep("/^DHL$/i", $xmlarrayresultdocsave, 
PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks for `DHL` exclusively on the line, and not the entire string. You'll want to do:

```
/^DHL.*$/i
```

Which matches `DHL` and everything else until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do exactly what you want.

```
$haystack = array(
    'Horse',
    'DHL',
    'DHL - 123',
    'Pedestrian',
    'Philosopher',
    'DHL-123',
    'DHL - 123'
);

$needle = 'DHL - ';

// Find all values with DHL
$test = array_filter($haystack, function($el) use ($needle) {
        return (strpos($el, $needle) !== false);
});

// Unset the values
foreach (array_keys($foundRows) as $key) {
    unset($haystack[$key]);
}
```